# How to calculate a whole row of number (dim as string) in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of number produced calculating by for loop

`Dim nextcell as String`

The value of the string nextcell are `3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8`, 
how can I add a statement to get a list of number `4, 5, 6, 3, 8, 9` (all added by 1) or `6, 8, 10, 4, 14, 16` (all multiplying by 2)?

I am thinking something like

```
Dim nextcell as String
Dim nextcell2 as String

nextcell2 = nextcell * 2
nextcell2 = nextcell - 1
```

but seems like VBA do not read it as string

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hoping for too much magic here. The variable you are starting with is a string and you can't do math with strings (unless they happen to be valid numbers, which a list of numbers isn't). Instead you will have to split it into an array (using `Split`) and work with each entry separately. When you are done, you will have to assemble it again, using `Join`.

```
Dim nextcell As String
Dim nextcell2 As String

nextcell = "3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8"

Values = Split(nextcell, ", ")
For i = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
    Values(i) = Values(i) + 1
Next
nextcell2 = Join(Values, ", ")
```

The `For` loop starts at the beginning of the array and processes each entry, using its index.